# Why is lambda not a function

Tags: functional-programming, racket

For Racket programming language, why is lambda not considered a function?
For example, it can't be defined as a higher order function like this.
`(define (my-lambda args body)
(lambda args body))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a key distinction that your question is missing:

1. `lambda` is **syntax**.
2. Procedures are **values**.

A `lambda` form is a form of expression whose value is a procedure.  The question whether "lambda is a function" starts off with a type error, so to speak, because lambdas and procedures don't live in the same world.

But let's set that aside.  The other way to look at this is by thinking of it in terms of **evaluation rules**.  The default Scheme evaluation rule, for the application of a procedure to arguments, can be expressed in pseudo-code like this:

```
(define (eval-application expr env)
  (let ((values
        ;; Evaluate each subexpression in the same environment as the 
        ;; enclosing expression, and collect the result values. 
        (map (lambda (subexpr) (eval subexpr env)) 
             expr)))
    ;; Apply the first value (which must be a procedure) to the
    ;; other ones in the results.
    (apply (car values) (cdr values))))
```

In English:

1. Evaluate all of the subexpressions in the same environment as the "parent".
2. `apply` the first result (which must have evaluated to a procedure) to the list of the rest.

And now, another reason `lambda` can't be a procedure is that this evaluation rule doesn't work for `lambda` expressions.  In particular, the point of `lambda` is to *not* evaluate its body right away!  This, in particular, is what afflicts your `my-lambda`—if you try to use it this way:

```
(my-lambda (x) (+ x x))
```

...the `(x)` in the middle must be immediately evaluated as an invocation of a procedure named `x` in the environment where the whole expression appears.  The `(+ x x)` must also be immediately evaluated.

So `lambda` requires its own evaluation rule.  As Basile's answer points out, this is normally implemented as a primitive in the Scheme system implementation, but we can sketch it in pseudocode with something like this:

```
;;;
;;; Evaluate an expression of this form, returning a procedure:
;;;
;;;     (lambda <formals> <body> ...)
;;;
(define (eval-lambda expr env)
  (let ((formals (second expr))
        (body (cddr expr)))
  ;; We don't evaluate `body` right away, we return a procedure.
  (lambda args
    ;; `formals` is never evaluated, since it's not really an 
    ;; expression on its own, but rather a subpart that cannot
    ;; be severed from its enclosing `lambda`.  Or if we want to
    ;; say it all fancy, the `formals` is *syncategorematic*...
    (let ((bindings (make-bindings formals args)))
      ;; When the procedure we return is called, *then* we evaluate 
      ;; the `body`--but in an extended environment that binds its
      ;; formal parameters to the arguments supplied in that call.
      (eval `(begin ,@body) (extend-environment env bindings))))))

;;;
;;; "Tie" each formal parameter of the procedure to the corresponding
;;; argument values supplied in a given call.  Returns the bindings
;;; as an association list.
;;;
(define (make-bindings formals args)
  (cond ((symbol? formals)
         `((,formals . args)))
        ((pair? formals)
         `((,(car formals) . ,(car args))
           ,@(make-bindings (cdr formals) (cdr args))))))
```

To understand this pseudocode, the time-tested thing is to study one of the many Scheme books that demonstrate how to build a meta-circular interpreter (a Scheme interpreter written in Scheme).  See for example [this section of *Structure and Interpretation of Computer programs*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node76.html).

Answer (score 2):

`lambda` needs to be a core language feature (like `if`, `let`, `define` are) in Scheme because it is constructing a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) so needs to manage the set of closed or [free variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) (and somehow put their binding in the closure).

For example:

```
(define (translate d) (lambda (x) (+ d x)))
```

When you invoke or evaluate `(translate 3)` the `d` is 3 so the dynamically constructed closure should remember that `d` is bound to 3. BTW, you generally want the result of `(translate 3)` and of `(translate 7)` be two *different* closures *sharing* some *common* code (but having different bindings for `d`).

Read also about [λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

Explaining that all in details requires an entire book. Fortunately, C. Queinnec has written it, so read his [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) book.

(If you read French, you could read the latest French [version](http://paracamplus.com/spip/?page=livre&isbn=978-2-916466-03-3) of that book)

See also the [Kernel programming language](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/~jshutt/kernel.html).

Read also wikipage about [evaluation strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy).

PS. You could, and some Lisp implementations (notably [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) and probably [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)) do that, define `lambda` as some [macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_%28computer_science%29) -e.g. which would expand to building some closure in an implementation specific way (but `lambda` cannot be defined as a function).

Comment: Nitpick on "needs" because if you have "lambda" then "if" can just be a macro where the two clauses become lambdas. I believe Clojure does this.

Comment: It might depend on call by value vs call by name. Indeed, in Lambda calculus *if* (and integers, and arithmetics) might be defined in terms of lambda. Practically speaking, this is not useful to *implement* pragmatically usable implementations of Scheme.

Answer (score 2):

A function call (e0 e1 e2) is evaluated like this

1. e0 is evaluated, the result is (hopefully) a function f
2. e1 is evaluated, the result is a value v1
3. e2 is evaluated, the result is a value v2
4. The function body of `f` is evaluated in an environment in which
   the formal parameters are bound to the values `v1` and `v2`.
   Note that all expressions e0, e1, and, e2 are evaluated before the body of the function is activated.

This means that a function call like  (foo #t 2 (/ 3 0)) will result in an error when (/ 3 0) is evaluated - before control is handed over to the body of foo.

Now consider the special form `lambda`. In `(lambda (x) (+ x 1))` this creates a function of one variable `x` which when called with a value `v` will compute `(+ v 1)`.

If in contrast `lambda` were a function, then the expressions `(x)` and `(+ x 1)` are evaluated before the body of `lambda` is activated. And now `(x)` will most likely produce an error - since `(x)` means call the function `x` with no arguments.

In short: Function calls will always evaluate all arguments, before the control is passed to the function body. If some expressions are not to be evaluated a special form is needed.

Here `lambda` is a form, that don't evaluate all subforms - so `lambda` needs to be a special form.

Answer (score -1):

*In Scheme lingo we use the term procedure instead of function throughout the standard report. Thus since this is about scheme dialects I'll use the term procedure.*

In eager languages like standard `#!racket` and `#!r6rs` procedures get their arguments evaluated before the body is evaluated with the new lexical environment. Thus since `if` and `lambda` has special evaluation rules than for procedures special forms and macros are the way to introduce new syntax.

In a lazy language like `#!lazy` racket evaluation is by need and thus many forms that are implemented as macros/special forms in an eager language can be implemented as procedure. eg. you can make `if` as a procedure using `cond` but you cannot make `cond` using `if` because the terms themselves would be evaluated as forms on access and eg `(cond (#t 'true-value))` would fail since `#t` is not a procedure. `lambda` has similar issue with the argument list.

Comment: I am a little disappointed that an experienced Scheme programmer would make the same mistake of so many Haskellers that macros are unnecessary in a lazy language. This is simply not true. There is a reason Template Haskell exists. While emulation of laziness can be accomplished with macros, they solve a much more general problem. Everything from DSLs to full compile-time static type systems (e.g. Typed Racket) can be implemented with macros—laziness cannot accomplish this.

Comment: @AlexisKing I have taken what I have heard for granted but I see now you can only replace macros with procedures where the only feature you are adding are controlled evaluation of the arguments. A form like `cond` is perhaps the simples example that my statement was false so I've added it. I've learned something new and I apparently need to play a little more with `#!lazy`  :-)